# How do I restrict uninstall of apps in the play store?

Tags: google-play-store

I have an android tablet. I also have a kid that doesn't understand enough to actually operate it properly, but more than enough to delete apps through the play store.

Restricting purchases from the play store is easy, but how do i password protect uninstalling apps from the play store?

I have seen a few apps to help me along, but they don't protect from the play store being launched from inside a game through a commercial for example.

How do i password protect either the entire play store, or the removal of apps?

Comment: Since you've got a tablet, have you had a look at [Restricted Profiles](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how do i password protect uninstalling apps from the play store?

This isn't possible as of today.

> I have seen a few apps to help me along, but they don't protect from the play store being launched from inside a game through a commercial for example.

Such behavior isn't made explicitly available to third-party apps, the ones that do exist today can only go so far in providing an "app-locker".

> How do i password protect either the entire play store, or the removal of apps?

You can't, at least not in a way that accounts for all scenarios. You may keep searching for "app-locker" apps that attempt to do this and hope you find one that fits your needs. Have you tried [Paranoid Android's Lockit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jedga.lockit)

Instead of going down this route, I'd recommend you setup multiple user profiles on the tablet (the assumption here being your tablet is running Android 4.2 or greater). In a multi-user scenario, if one user uninstalls an app, it's only uninstalled within their profile. You may [read more about it here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/14/android-4-2-feature-highlight-multiple-user-accounts/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of apps for kids, where you can set a mode and only allow certain apps on child mode and you being an adult administrator can unlock other apps, I've used one called [Kids Shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whisperarts.kidsshell) it got the job done for me

Comment: [Kido's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kidoz&hl=en) is another option.